# PHP: Serving files hosted on a different server

Tags: php, apache, curl, header

i have following problem:
I have some big files on a server who runs under plesk, and i want to exclude them from the regular plesk backup, but as far as i've seen this is not possible.

So i would like to store these big files on another server and serve them through the web app which runs on the first server.

The problem is that the url of the files should be hidden for the user. Now i have implemented that with php's header().
Of course they should be served directly to the user and not through the first server, as the files are really big!

In short, what i need is, when the user clicks the file download link, he should receive the file from the second server, but the file url should not be visible to him.

Im using php for my application and apache as a webserver,
i would be grateful for any suggestions on how to approach this problem,

Harry

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the user has to get acceptance from the first server to download the file. This is why i need the url of the file to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the include or require_once function to get the data from those files without actually "viewing" the file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the user downloading the file must be eligible/allowed to download it. This information is stored on the first server's database.

Comment: If your using a database just use the mysqli_connect command and you can put the username/password in that. If you want the person to have permission to download the file then have them login first. Remember to use POST instead of GET to hide the info in the url.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is receiving a file from server2.domain.com then there is no way to make them think it is coming from server.domain.com unless the file passes through server.domain.com

If the user is directly requesting the file from the second server then they will be able to find out where it is coming from.

The only real way to totally hide the evidence of the other server from users is to proxy the file via server 1. You can either do this using a proxy server or by reading and echoing the file via php.

Comment: hm ok, the thing is that the user should only have access to this file requested, if he has it on his account, the server should not be hidden but the file url itself.how should i serve the url of the second server without knowing if the user is eligible to download the file, can i pass the session data to the second server?

Comment: Make the file download url a php script that connects back to the first servers database to see if they have permission to download the file. As they are different servers, they wont share session data unless you store the session data in a database. The alternative is to include an encrypted expiry in the url when it is generated and decode this on server 2 before allowing them to download the file.

Comment: This seems like a legit workaround. I thought it could be implemented somehow easier only on the first server, just getting the file with curl or something, or would this mean that the file would "go through the first server" too?

Comment: Curling the file from the second server will still pass the file through the first server